# [Authorize(Roles="xx") seems no working in asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jwt, access-token

I am working with an ASP.NET web API project (not .NET Core). I want to add `[Authorize(Roles="xx")` to my controller action. But it seems not working (always 401, Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request.").

I promise the request has an access token and the token has a role claim.

if  I remove `(Role="xx")` then it works.  I notice that the role claim is the lower case while "Roles" is the upper case, is that the reason?

Help me, please

Comment: same issue here, but with .net core

Comment: Have u found anything?